# yepnope.js ie7/ie8 jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, slider, yepnope

I have created a slider and it looks pretty bad in ie7, and not much better in ie8. The rest of the browsers render the animation fine. I would like to replace the side with a simple crossfade in ie7 and 8.

Can I use yepnope.js to do this and if so how?

Comment: Why does it look "look pretty bad" in IE?

Comment: I have just done a regular ie conditional, but there are some conflicts - 'pretty bad  - the jquery animation is very poor and stutters.

Comment: @welovedesign Your conditional comments won't work in IE10, so I would encourage you to figure out how to make the script run better in IE.

Comment: ie9 is ok, so suppose ie9 will be but how do I target a more basic form of the slider for ie7&8